# python single element tuple

Tags: python, indexing, tuples

Suppose I have a matrix `M` and an indexing set `idx=[(0,1),(2,3),(3,2)]` and I want to create two sets of tuples, `idx_leq1` consisting of those tuples whose first and second elements are both less than or equal to 1 and `idx_geq2` consisting of those tuples whose first and second elements are both greater than or equal to 2.

I want to access the elements `M[idx_leq1]` and `M[idx_geq2]` cleanly. I have tried `idx_leq1 = tuple([e for e in idx if e[0]<=1 and e[1]<=1])`, but this returns `idx_leq1 = ((0,1),)` which I can't use to index `M`. On the other hand, `idx_geq2 = tuple([e for e in idx if e[0]>=2 and e[1]>=2]) = ((2,3),(3,2))` works.

How can I solve this for the case where my first index set consists of only one coordinate pair? I don't want to do `M[idx_leq1[0]]`.

I can do: `list(chain(*[(e,) for e in idx if e[0]<=1 and e[1]<=1]))` and `list(chain(*[(e,) for e in idx if e[0]>=2 and e[1]>=2]))`, but then I still have to grab the first element for `idx_leq1` whereas I can pass `idx_geq2` to `M` and grab the appropriate elements.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to me the first result should work just as well as the second. Are you iterating over it in the same way? And you cant index M with a tuple of tuples in either case.

Comment: The first case doesn't give me back the `(0,0)` entry of `M` but rather something like the whole matrix

Answer (score 0):

[Tested with `numpy.mat`]

`[M[0, 1]]` should be fetched as in `M[[0], [1]]`. When indexing matrix, *Multidimensional list-of-locations indexing* requires k lists of index each working with one dimension.

For example, in order to fetch `M[0, 3], M[1, 4], M[2, 5]`, one should use `M[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]`. In other word, the index that you give to `M` should not be considered lists of coordinates. Rather, they are lists of "coordinates on each dimension".
In your case, a `M[[0, 1]]` (or its equivalent in tuple type) fetches `M[0], M[1]` as `[0, 1]` is considered to work on the first dimension, and the second dimension is broadcasted.

Ref: http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Indexing.html#Multidimensional-list-of-locations-indexing
This reference believes that the reason to use "list of dims" rather than "list of coordinates" is to save number of instances, as unpacking many tuples might be expensive.